# Cannot set Diskquota on CentOS7 Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted (but it is)

Tags: centos, disk-space-utilization

I am currently trying to set disk-quota for groups (in the home-directory) of a CentOS7 installation. Sadly there is a problem at the very beginning.

I have set the options in the /etc/fstab:
...

```
    /dev/mapper/centos-home /home                   xfs   defaults,grpquota        1 2
   /dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

afterwards i have remounted the /home partition with:

```
mount -o remount /home
```

This seemed to work, as the options where set in the partition:

```
mount | grep /home
/dev/mapper/centos-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,grpquota)
```

But now, it I try to activate the diskquota, the following happens:

```
quotacheck -cugv /home
quotacheck: Skipping /dev/mapper/centos-home [/home]
quotacheck: Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.
```

I do not really know where so search, because the options, of which the system is complaining, are set.

Does someone got an idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

most sincerely
Twinhand

Answer (score 2):

Try using the xfs tools (*), like:

```
xfs_quota -x -c 'report -h' /fs
```

There's no need to run quotacheck on xfs, xfs does that internally after quota is turned on and will always be consistent.

(*) It's better to use only xfs quota tools for xfs as there's (was) a bug in the quota package (1) which does not report group quotas for xfs correctly. It's marked as fix in version quota-4.00-4.el7 but I get the same error in version quota-4.01-11.el7.x86_64 See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=836200

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay it worked, but is there a possibility to set group-quotas with xfs_quota which use ldap groups? Because it is complaining that groupx is not appearing in the /etc/group file.

Comment: @Twinhand I think the group must be a unix group, i.e. to resolve via getent group <group>, in ldap (openldap) that's called a posixGroup

Comment: Hmm thats interesting, it is  complaining, that there is no Unix group (its a posix group) but when I am trying to create the group it says "has already been created" it is also not working with the unix group, it says xfs_quota -x -c 'limit -g  isoft=500 ihard=700 groupx'
xfs_quota: cannot set limits: Function not implemented
xfs_quota: cannot set limits: Function not implemented